# Кодировка русских символов при отправке формы в groovy скрипт

Tags: servlet, groovy

Отправляю данные с формы в скрипт:

```
    println """
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>

            <body>
                <p>${defaultPath}</p>
                <form action="afterAuth.groovy" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Название файла: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="text">Текст файла: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="text">
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="submit"></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """
```

Получаю так:

```
    def name = params.get("name")
    def text = params.get("text")
```

Прилетает некорректная кодировка: Ð° Ð°.

Как быть здесь?

P.S. На текущий момент помог только фильтр на Java.